# How to pass an Unix command output to Python function

Tags: python, shell, fabric

I have a requirement where i need to run one docker command on my local machine and send this list to remote server and check whether those images are existing or not. I need to rerun list of images that are not existing on remote server to local server. I need to do it with python. I have written some code by mixing shell and python as below.

```
List=$(docker images -q | grep "docker pull" | awk '{print $3}') #this command is mandatory to get exact docker name.
fab remote_sync_system_spec_docker_to_aws_artifactory:List -u ${USERNAME} -H 1.2.3.4
```

I am tryting pass output of shell command i.e List to pyhon function through fab as above.That function looks like below.

```
def remote_sync_system_spec_docker_to_aws_artifactory(List):
for line in List:
if( os.popen("docker images -q $line") == none )
List=... #need to prepare list and return back to calling function.
```

once i get the list on remote server, i need to return back it to calling function and i can do some manipulations there. basically i can use shell but problem is with connecting to remote server with sshpass is not accepted in my project so looking for python script.

Comment: `docker images -q` prints just the hex identifier, one per line.  If you expect output with multiple fields, I guess you are looking for just `docker images`?

Comment: I don't see how Fabric improves the situation with regard to SSH, it just obscures the fact that you are using regular SSH under the hood.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a simple way to transport a list, I would suggest a pipeline rather than a variable.

```
docker images -q | awk '/docker pull/ { print $3 }' |
fab remote_sync_system_spec_docker_to_aws_artifactory_stdin -u ${USERNAME} -H 1.2.3.4
```

where the function is something like

```
import sys, subprocess

def remote_sync_system_spec_docker_to_aws_artifactory_stdin (handle=sys.stdin):
    """
    Read Docker image identifiers from file handle; check which
    ones are available here, and filter those out; return the rest.
    """
    missing = ()
    for line in handle:
        repo = line.rstrip('\n')
        if subprocess.run(['docker', 'images', '-q', repo],
                stdout=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True).stdout == "":
            missing.append(repo)
    return missing
```

Comment: I will note again that `docker images -q | awk '/docker pull/` can never print anything useful, and suggest that perhaps you mean to drop the `-q` option here.

Comment: As a matter of fact, it also seems that `docker images -q deadbeef0bad` doesn't print anything either, so that part of the logic will need to be reviewed as well.

Comment: i think you are confused with my requirement. I need to run a simple unix command and get output of it in a variable and pass that variable as a parameter to a function. This should be written in python.

Comment: What I am suggesting here is *don't* put that in a variable.  You can, but it's clunky and inelegant.  Reading the output from the other command as your standard input sits well with existing Unix tools and allows you to approach the problem fairly elegantly and idiomatically.

Comment: Eventually I suppose you could do the entire process in Python, and then passing an arbitrarily complex variable between functions is not an issue.

Comment: when you are returning missing, where are you receiving it on the calling side?

Comment: I don't see that part of your code and I'm not really familiar with Fabric so I can't say I know the answer to that.  Whatever calls this function will receive the result.

Comment: your solution of piping docker images command to python function is working nicely. But when i return missing from python function how can i capture that in a shell variable List=$(docker images -q | awk '/docker pull/ { print $3 }' |
fab remote_sync_system_spec_docker_to_aws_artifactory_stdin -u ${USERNAME} -H 1.2.3.4). This way is not working. any idea

Comment: If you want to capture the resulting list, just print it.  The command substitution captures the pipeline's standard output.  But the point of this is to avoid having to store the result in a shell variable.  (Printing it might be useful for other reasons, though.)

Comment: I need to capture it in a variable on my local machine and need to some more manipulations. So please can you tell me how to do it

Comment: Print. The. Result.  Though capturing it in a variable is *still* an antipattern. Feeding it to yet another shell pipeline is usually the sane way to do it, or convert the whole thing into Python if you need detailed flow control with error checking at various stages of the pipeline.

Comment: `shellvariable="$(python -c 'print("something")')"` puts the "something" in `shellvariable`.  But `python -c 'print("something")' | wc -l` is a much better way than `shellvariable=$(python ....); wc -l <<<"$shellvariable"` for example.

Answer (score 0):

```
os.popen()
```

will return and object in memory, what you should do is

```
def remote_sync_system_spec_docker_to_aws_artifactory(List):
    for line in List:
        if( os.popen("docker images -q $line").read() == none ):
            List=... #need to prepare list and return back to calling function.
```

Comment: i am getting error fab remote_sync_system_spec_docker_to_aws_artifactory:List -u ${USERNAME} -H 1.2.3.4 at this line as syntax error near unexpected token `(' even though i have not used bracket. How can i pass List to python function.

Comment: The error message looks unrelated to the code posted in this answer.

Comment: how can i pass output of os.popen to python function with fab?

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid `os.popen()` and even its replacement `subprocess.Popen()` if all you need is to obtain the output from a shell command.

For recent Python 3.x, use `subprocess.run()`:

```
import subprocess

List = ()
for result in subprocess.run(["docker", "images", "-q"],
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True).stdout.split('\n'):
    if 'docker pull' in result:
        List.append(result.split()[3])
```

In Python 2.x the corresponding function was `subprocess.check_output()`.

Maybe you'll want to replace the `grep` with something a bit more focused; `'docker pull' in result` will look for the string anywhere in the line, but you would probably like to confine it to just a particular column, for example.

Comment: I will explain my requirement with example. Docker images in local server returns 10 images and i need to to check how many images are existing on remote server out of those 10 and i need to return non existing images to local server. In my code List has images which are on my local machine and i am passing it to remote server with fab command. The function def remote_sync_system_spec_docker_to_aws_artifactory(List): is checking for images in remote server. how can i pass list to this function and read its contents.

Comment: Are you asking how to access a shell variable from Python?  That would be something like [`os.environ`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.environ) in Python but it's not at all clear from your question if that's what you are after.  Should I remove this answer and post a different one explaining that?

Comment: ... But it would make a lot more sense to code the entire flow in Python anyway; the shell only supports strings, not arrays or lists (portably).